# How to manage relation using PHP-activerecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, phpactiverecord

I've an existing project in Code Igniter with HMVC extension. Also using php-activerecord through sparc.

For a new module, I created two tables with one-to-many relationship, enforced directly at DB level (in MySQL). Tables are say 'nassignment' (PK id) and 'nassignment_assignee' (FK assignment_id).

Under models, I created two class 'nassignment.php' having class Nassignment and 'nassignment_assignee.php' with class name Nassignment_assignee.

Below is the code I'm trying in controller

```
$this->load->model("nassignment");
$nAssignmentArr = $this->nassignment->all();
```

and getting following error

```
[Fri Aug 02 13:50:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 
exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Nassignmentassignee does not exist' 
in /home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-
activerecord/lib/Reflections.php:33\nStack trace:\n#0 
/home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-
activerecord/lib/Reflections.php(33): ReflectionClass-
>__construct('Nassignmentassi...')\n#1 
/home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-
activerecord/lib/Relationship.php(286): ActiveRecord\\Reflections-
>add('Nassignmentassi...')\n#2 /home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-
activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Relationship.php(281): 
ActiveRecord\\AbstractRelationship->set_class_name('Nassignmentassi...')\n#3 
/home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-
activerecord/lib/Relationship.php(464): ActiveRecord\\AbstractRelationship-
>set_inferred_class_name()\n#4 /home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-
activerecord/0.0 in /home/kapil/projects/<project>/application/sparks/php-
activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Reflections.php on line 33
```

Model code is

nassignment.php

```
class Nassignment Extends ActiveRecord\Model{
    static $table_name = 'nassignment';
    //Work fine if I remove following line, but do not get data
    static $has_many = array(
            array('nassignment_assignee')
        );
}
```

nassignment_assignee.php

```
class Nassignment_assignee Extends ActiveRecord\Model{
    static $table_name = 'nassignment_assignee';
}
```

Any suggesations, why it is not working

Comment: I think I may have a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075807/codeigniter-on-1and1-error-reporting). Why is no one attempting these questions?

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that the name of the file matches the name of the class in case also. See [the solution to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239469/393021)

Apparently, libraries too have to be named accordind to the UCfirst naming convention.