# CodeIgniter on 1and1 Error Reporting

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, codeigniter-2, phpactiverecord

I made a website with CodeIgniter and I am currently **hosting it with 1and1**. During development, everything looked golden. Only if all hosts were as reliable as localhost.

I am looking to get the **PHP error logs** from the site. Unfortunately, 1and1 does not allot access to their Apache logs. How can I get error logs? Debugging fatal errors is a pain without logs.

What I have tried?

1. The [custom error logging](http://pixelfundi.com/blog/pixelfundi/php-custom-error-reporting/) function
2. Modifying the local PHP.ini to allow/log errors
3. Used php5 by adding the necessary `AddHandler` and `AddType` clauses to my `.htaccess`

Still the problem is not fixed.

**Update (October 1st)**
Still trying to fix my issue, I have narrowed it down to the PHP ActiveRecord spark. The models which inherit from PHP ActiveRecord are not instantiated. PHP ActiveRecord's `ActiveRecord\Model` class is instantiated. I did this using the following snippet

```
    $class_name = "ActiveRecord\Model";
    echo in_array($class_name, get_declared_classes());
```

which returns a `1` for `ActiveRecord\Model` and `0` for `MyActiveRecordModel`.

Supposedly, there is some friction between the ActiveRecord spark and and 1and1—my guess, DB problems. Here comes the interesting part. Using the ActiveRecord library provided by CodeIgniter works like a charm. I presume PHP ActiveRecord is printing some errors of what is going wrong. This is what I want to get from 1and1.

**Update (October 8th)**
If I manually require `MyActiveRecordModel`, the code snippet that checks for definition of classes claims `ActiveRecord\Model` is not defined.

Comment: It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-php-codeigniter

Comment: have you defined the error log file path in config file?!

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan which of the configuration files do you refer to? The configuration file for CodeIgniter is properly setup and CodeIgniter runtime information is being logged. What I cannot get to are the PHP error logs

Comment: @dianuj no it cannot. How do I get PHP error logs is what I asj

Comment: Writing a custom error handler should help you, but it seems that it doesn't? You should tell us (in your question!) what you tried exactly, what happened etc.

Comment: I have written a custom error message reporter but it's incapable of bringing me the errors I need.

Comment: @Nanne I just updated the question. Take a look (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by changing the naming conventions. The file which had `MyActiveRecordModel` was named *myActiveRecordModel*. This did not allow CodeIgniter to autoload the required class.

I got this tip from a [list of steps for upgrading CodeIgniter](https://www.chuongduong.net/ci3/installation/upgrade_300.html) to version 3.0.0—although, I am on version 2.1.3